# Angular change the value after EventEmitter

Tags: angular

I have a component that is a sort of toggle functionality.

```
  <label *ngIf="value" (click)="toogleLuckBet()">On</label>
  <label *ngIf="!value" (click)="toogleLuckBet()">Off</label>

export class GameStarComponent {
  @Input() value: boolean;
  @Input() disabled: boolean;
  @Output() valueChange = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  constructor() {
    this.value = false;
    this.disabled = false;
  }

  toogleLuckBet() {
    this.value = !this.value;
    this.valueChange.emit(this.value);
  }

}
```

This component is being used inside a foreach and what I would like to do is based on certain conditions of other fields allow the value to change or not. So my idea was to have a valueChanged when calling that component

```
<game-star [(value)]="game.isLuckBet" (valueChange)="changeLuckBet()"></game-star>
```

And on the parent component, implement the function changeLuckBet that would check the scenario and if necessary change the value of the game.isLuckBet property back to false.

What happens is that even that I see the property changed while debugging, after everything the property is in the true state, as if I never changed it on the parent component.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Can u try using property binding instead of two way binding
by changing

```
[(value)]="game.isLuckBet" 

To

[value]="game.isLuckBet"
```